# How to set profile picture in xmpp aSmack android?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

Can anyone help me to set profile picture through aSmack library in android. Here I am using the openfire server. I am able create the account using following line,

```
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager
                        .getInstance(connection);
    accountManager.createAccount(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

But, I cannot set profile picture. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dear you have to use vCard class for this purpose.
and this will store on server in vCard table in php panel.
 use method to store Additional info.

```
private void loadVCard(XMPPConnection conn, String username) {
    VCard vcard = new VCard();

    //ProviderManager.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());



    vcard.load(conn, username);


    vcard.setFirstName("" + username);
    vcard.setEmailHome("" + email);
    vcard.setMiddleName("" + middleName);
    vcard.setNickName("" + nickName);
    vcard.setPhoneHome("Voice", "" + phoneNumber);
    vcard.setLastName("" + lastName);
    vcard.setOrganization("" + orginiZation);
    vcard.setAvatar("" + image_path); //Image Path should be URL or Can be Byte Array etc.


        vcard.save(conn);

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply bro. I will check and update you.

Comment: The `addIQProvider` is not necessary with the lastest (a)Smack version.